# Keep old kernels

Tags: apt, kernel

I am doing experiments with few Linux kernels, also I want to keep all the kernels on my system; I don't want then to be removed automatically. how do I achieve that?

(NOTE: I have mounted `/boot` on separate 4GB partition so space is not an issue)

Comment: You can keep them by not removing them, Ubuntu will not remove old kernels automatically.

Comment: @Ron as far as I know if you install new kernel, old kernels are removed by apt automatically

Comment: No it will not. Just installed 4.1.1 and my old one is still there.

Comment: @Ron is the all the three old kernels still available in grub? when i receive kernel update one oldest kernel is removed

Comment: I had only 1 before, so now it is 2

Comment: @Ron you cannot have more than 3 (by default)

Answer (score 3):

Update: New releases like Jammy is using `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove`

This answer was for some old releases which uses `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` to generate `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels`.

So you can create new file APT configuration file same way, kind of an override.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels-stop
```

contains:

```
APT::NeverAutoRemove
{
   "^linux-image-*-generic$";
   "^linux-headers-*-generic$";
   "^linux-image-extra-*-generic$";
   "^linux-signed-image-*-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-*-generic$";
   "^linux-tools-*-generic$";
};
```